# Create objects with unique functionality but same type of data

Tags: c++, function, object

I want to create multiple objects that operate on the same data, but each has a different function it performs on that data.

I attempted to do this like so:

```
class test
{
    public:
        test(int x, int y)
        {  
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        }
        int (*func)();

    private:
        int x;
        int y;
};

int test1()
{
    this->x += 100;
    return this->x; 
}

int test2()
{
    this->x -= 100;
    return this->x; 
}

int main()
{
    test t1(1,2);
    t1.func = &test1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

But, it didn't compile. Since test1 and test2 don't even know about x (nor about this pointer).
How can I make it work?
Perhaps I'm trying to accomplish this using the wrong tools?

Comment: Your first problem is that there is no `this` pointer in either `test1` or `test2` since they aren't member functions. And since `x` is also private you would have to declare them as `friend` functions in `test`. There are easier alternatives, such as inheritance, or perhaps some sort of template?

Comment: I don't want them to be members of this class... assume there are 1000 test objects.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't add getter (and setter) functions to `test` so that you can access the data from outside the class? Then your functions could just take the `test` object as argument (e.g.: as `const test&`) - and you might even avoid all the function pointer stuff (assuming there isn't any real need for it)

Comment: In that case I could've just used structs, no? I want to be able to track how this data changes after each invocation of func on a particular test object. While each test object should have it's own function that manipulates this data differently.

Comment: `struct` and `class` are the same thing in C++, they only differ by default access modifier. And I don't understand how getters and setters interfere with your tracking (or how you would track data changes in your current attempt)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

- You want your private data be private
- You will probably want to use function pointer, but not a pointer to class method

What can you do:

- Make a helper function that accepts this pointer and structure with private data
- Call it with helper function

It will be difficult to make it in too clean way as I guess.
Here is my example:

```
class test {
public:
    test(int x, int y) {  
        private_data.x = x;
        private_data.y = y;
    }
    struct PrivateData {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    int (*func)(test*, PrivateData*);
    int call_func() {
        return func(this, &private_data);
    }
private:
    PrivateData private_data;
};

int test1(test *self, test::PrivateData *private_data) {
    private_data->x += 100;
    return private_data->x; 
}

int test2(test *self, test::PrivateData *private_data) {
    private_data->x -= 100;
    return private_data->x; 
}

int main() {
    test t1(1,2);
    t1.func = test1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works :)
I will experiment with this some more

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! Do you, by any chance, know how can I assign t1.call_func to another function pointer of type: int (*fPptr)(); ? I need something like fPtr = &t1.call_func.

Comment: Wow. call_func looks extremely simple. Why do you want to take it like a pointer? It is just a helper function to call `func` itself.

Comment: It's a long story... maybe I'm doing all of this wrong.. but anyway, I have a callback function - that isn't aware of the existence of "test" objects at all - it just wants to get int output.  (so it is just a function in the form of int (*fPtr)() that I switch every time with other values - one of them happens to be pointing at t1.call_func...)

Comment: But how do you create a test object? You can't just call a method of that without knowing an address of object in memory. call_func is not castable to function pointer, due it is only castable to member method pointer.

Comment: maybe you can save it as a void* pointer?

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I will try to find a better way.. it seems I over-complicated this:D